# NumPy adds a dot after each element of an array which I can’t strip

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to write code which generates a sound file based on a series of frequencies I give it, but I have reached a point where compiling the arrays of integer values together puts a decimal point after each one which corrupts the sound file I'm generating.

I've tried converting it into a list, turning all elements into integer values, and then converting it back. This removes the dots, but it still corrupts the file.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

# Samples per second
sps = 44100

# Duration
duration = 0.1

def wavegen(build):
    final_array = np.array([])
    for i in build:
        freq = i
        eachnum = np.arange(duration * sps)
        waveform = np.sin(2 * np.pi * eachnum * freq / sps)
        waveform_quiet = waveform * 0.3
        waveform_integers = np.int16(waveform_quiet * 32767)
        final_array  = np.append(final_array, waveform_integers)

    print(final_array)
    write('sine.wav', sps, final_array)

wavegen([100, 50, 100, 50])
```

And the array generated looks like this:

```
[   0.  140.  280. ... -210. -140.  -70.]
```

Comment: I tried your code. It works for me. What is a corrupted file?

Comment: My other python code cant open the file and windows gives me error 0xc00d5212. however audacity opens it

Comment: The "dots" are because the values are floats, they're probably being cast during the `np.append()` because the initial `final_array` doesn't have a defined data type and will probably default to float64

Comment: I'm using Foobar2000 and it works. It's probably just that your player doesn't support this format.

Comment: ok so if i define the array as interger could it fix it

Comment: no cus if i just have one integer array it opens fine

Comment: `scipy` can take floats and integers, that's not a problem. Read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html).

Comment: ok that makes sense but even after i run final_array.astype(int) there are still dots after it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that you are getting the decimal places is because `final_array = np.array([])` is creating a float type array. When you append your integer array `waveform_integers` with the float type array `final_array`, you get a float type array because `final_array` is set to use floats.

To fix this, you can use `final_array = np.array([], dtype='int16')` which will make it so that both arrays in `np.append` are `int16` arrays and the result is also an `int16` array.

Comment: thx so much that gets rid of the points and the file isnt corupted i just have some plaback issues i need to iron out

Answer (score 0):

The use of `np.append` in a loop is inefficient.  List append is better, since it works in-place.  `np.append` is a cover function for `np.concatenate`, which makes a whole new array (with all the involved copying) each call.

```
def wavegen(build):
    alist = []
    for i in build:
        freq = i
        eachnum = np.arange(duration * sps)
        waveform = np.sin(2 * np.pi * eachnum * freq / sps)
        waveform_quiet = waveform * 0.3
        alist.append(waveform_integers * 32767)
    final_array = np.array(alist)      # 2d result
    # or final_array = np.hstack(alist)     # 1d
    final_array = final_array.astype(np.int16)  # change the dtype just once
    return final_array
```